# Looking for Lightning Testnet Wallet with Lnurl capabilities

Tags: wallet, lightning-network, testnet

I'm looking to test an lnurl withdrawal. I created an lnurl withdrawal url using the OpenNode api. I have an [htlc.me](https://htlc.me/) testnet lightning wallet. But it doesn't seem to have a way to input lnurls.

Is there a testnet lightning wallet that allows you to scan lnurls?

I don't have android, I know some only work on android. Zap claims to have one but they're an open source app that hasn't worked for me and seems to be not maintained so frequently.